How do I set sync_dist and rank_zero_only in PyTorch lightning logging when using multiple GPU?
I'm using PyTorch lightning DDP with  four (4) GPUs to train a model. I noticed when logging there's option to set sync_dist=True and rank_zero_only =True in training step or validation step. What do they mean and what is the correct way to set them?
